# @EnableScheduling in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am new to Spring Boot. Wanted to enable `@EnableScheduling` and `@Scheduled` in my Spring Boot application. Have written as below but how do I call it.

```
       @EnableScheduling
       public class Application {
           public static void main(String[] args) {
           SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
       }
```

Comment: @Scheduled on a method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use Spring @Scheduled annotation .Below is the code to use in
Spring Boot.

```
        import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
        import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
        import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
        import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
        import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
        import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
        import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
        import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;


        @SpringBootApplication
        @Configuration
        @ComponentScan
        @EnableAutoConfiguration
        @EnableScheduling
        public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{
           public static void main(String[] args) {
              SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
           }

           @Override
           protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
               return application.sources(Application.class);
           }

           private static Class<Application> applicationClass = Application.class;

        }
```

---

```
    import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


    @Component
    public class ScheduledTasks {

            @Scheduled(cron = "0 39 00 * * ?")
            public void scheduleFixedDelayTask() {
                System.out.println("Fixed delay task - " + System.currentTimeMillis()/1000);
            }



    }
```

Output in console :

Fixed delay task - 1482952140

Answer (score 3):

There is a good tutorial about your problem: https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/

You need to annotate application with `@EnableScheduling`:

```
@EnableScheduling
public class SpringGuideApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringGuideApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

and then in your class:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

@Component
public class Scheduler {
    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Scheduler.class);

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000)
    public void reportCurrentTime() {
        log.info("Scheduler: the time is now {}", dateFormat.format(new Date()));
    }
}
```